# UIText field does not respond to touch after switching view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

In my app, I have a text field that works fine, however after going back to the main menu and then back onto the page with the text field, the text field becomes un-touchable, the keyboard does not show no matter how many times you click it.

Here is a screen shot of the interface http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=y11sm&s=6

I think I may have to add code or connect an action with the text field, but how?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you show some code or interface information?

Comment: My first guess would be that an invisible object (view) prevents you from tapping the text field. If so, you can use removeFromSuperview to remove subviews that you don't need anymore. Of course, I could be wrong since I have no idea what your situation is.

Comment: The view containing the text field may also have been disabled. Check that `yourContainingView.userInteractionEnabled` is set to `YES`

Comment: sorry, here is a screen shot of the interface http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=y11sm&s=6

Answer (score 1):

You can remove subviews that you don't use anymore like @Kim has already told you or if you need these subviews but they are blocking the action, you can bring your textfield to front using,

```
[your_view bringSubviewToFront: your_textfield];
```

Comment: where do I put this code?  and what would I replace "your_view" with?

Comment: Your_view is `self` if your are trying to bring it to front in your view or `self.view` if you are inside your view controller.

Comment: I am getting the error "no known class method for selector 'bringSubviewToFront' "